# integrating videos in chatbot using pandorabots

Tags: video, chatbot, media, aiml, pandorabots

I’m developing with pandorabots and I really like it, but I have one problem. It’s integrating videos into the chatbot.
The only format that works is, for example.

**http://www.alex-bernardini.fr/videos/Wildlife.mp4**

Any other URL format doesn’t work.
If I host the videos, I can't impose this format.
Can you propose a solution for this?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What format are you wanting to include in your chatbot?

Comment: Any format like a youtube video or Vimeo, in fact, any video.

Comment: But you know the URL to the video right?

Comment: yes, but in the simulator, I can't see the video.

Comment: Can you provide the URL to the video?

Comment: yes, this is it.   https://vimeo.com/761481637

Comment: That's a URL to a webpage not a video. It says I have to log in to watch it.

Comment: thanks, can you try this one.  https://app.videas.fr/v/a70a5399-a712-4f9c-b2ae-9d0f6e6bdd2c/

Comment: Sorry but that's not a video file either. Videos will end with names like .mp4 or .ogg

Comment: how do i host videos to the format  .mp4 or .ogg??

Comment: Is the video file yours? Upload it to your webspace and then you can link it as you did the wildlife video in your post.